# ValueError: X has 14 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 148409 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I trained model with Random Forest Classifier. I saved this model using pickle. Then, in different python file, I preprocessed a sentence from input (I vectorized it in Bag of Words and then in TF-IDF). After that I used `train_test_split` with the parameter `test_size=1` to make this sentence look like a test data. When I give this test data to my trained model it says:

> ValueError: X has 14 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 148409 features as input

Probably it's because i used dataset to train my model and now it's only 1 sample. But how am I supposed to use my model if 1 sample array (or matrix) doesn't have the same shape as an array with thousands samples from dataset?
Shapes while training:

```
train dataset features size: (23588, 148409)
train dataset label size: (23588,)
test dataset features size: (10110, 148409)
test dataset label size: (10110,)
```

Shape of one sentence when I try to use my model (as an example):

```
text_test shape (15, 14)
```

Code in training (building) python file:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
BoW_transformer = vectorizer.fit(data['Text'])
BoW_data = BoW_transformer.transform(data['Text'])
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(BoW_data)
data_tf_idf = tf_idf_transformer.transform(BoW_data)
text_train, text_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(
    data_tf_idf, data['Label'], test_size=0.3
)
print(f"train dataset features size: {text_train.shape}")
print(f"train dataset label size: {label_train.shape}")
print(f"test dataset features size: {text_test.shape}")
print(f"test dataset label size: {label_test.shape}")
RF_classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
RF_classifier.fit(text_train, label_train)
predict_train = RF_classifier.predict(text_train)
predict_test = RF_classifier.predict(text_test)
```

Code in 'use' python file:

```
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
BoW_transformer = vectorizer.fit(input_string)
BoW_data = BoW_transformer.transform(input_string)
tf_idf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(BoW_data)
data_tf_idf = tf_idf_transformer.transform(BoW_data)
text_test, label_test = train_test_split(
    data_tf_idf, test_size=1
)
print("text_test shape", text_test.shape)
with open("saved_model.pickle", 'rb') as f:
    RF_classifier = pickle.load(f)
predict_test = RF_classifier.predict(text_test)
```

I tried to put messages in array when I use fit() but I get either an error or my computer freezes (probably my RAM is not enough to train model with numpy arrays)
I tried to reshape it but I cannot reshape array with sum=210 into array with sum=3000000...

Comment: you have put part of the code in which is great but the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Make sure you put your test data through the same pre-processing steps as your training data.  For example if could be that you've one-hot encoded your training data and not your test data.

Comment: Chris, if we are talking about "cleaning" text (deleting stop words, lemmatization and so on) then I did the same thing with 1 sentence as with dataset of samples. Both dataset and 1 sample are cleaned (training is going well, ~99% of accuracy. Problems start when I do 1 sample test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on Russian Stackoverflow: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493423/Почему-возникает-ошибка-valueerror](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493423/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-valueerror)

Translated:
The problem is in the preparation of features. You need to prepare all features identically.
If you are using transformers with internal state and using `fit()` on the data you are using to train the model then you need to save the transformers with `pickle`, just like your model. And when you want to make a prediction, you need to read the transformers and use only `transform()`, no `fit()`.

Also there are some transformers without internal state. For example, you can use `HashingVectorizer()` instead of `CountVectorizer()`. `HashingVectorizer()` doesn't have internal state, so it consumes less memory than `CountVectorizer()` and you don't need to save it, you just need to initialize it with the same arguments.